# WatiN - Which resource contains Attribute [TestMethod] or [Test]?

Tags: resources, attributes, watin

I am just beginning WatiN and in a lot of blogs I see attributes like [TestMethod] or simply [Test] used.

For Example:

 [MSForge Blog Post](http://msforge.net/blogs/janko/archive/2008/03/27/unit-testing-aspx-pages-with-watin-tool.aspx)

etc. etc.

but when I attempt:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using WatiN.Core;
using WatiN.Core.UnitTests;
using WatiN.Core.Constraints;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace Lemmings
{
    class Login
    {
        [TestMethod]
           ...
           ...
     }
}
```

[TestMethod]/[Test] is not recognized. I haven't seen anyone state that it is a custom attribute (it would also be strange if everyone was using the same custom attribute that was named the same thing) so I don't think that is likely.

What am I missing?

Note: For simple scripts [STAThread] works but if I want to use something like "ie.goto" VS2008 complains.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Mel,

The Test and testmethod are custom attributes that are used by unit testing tools so they know that the method is a test. The Test attribute is used by nUnit and test method is used by the Visual Studio testing tools.

For more information you should look into the getting started documenation on [www.nunit.org](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=quickStart&r=2.5), and download the nunit test runner.

Oh you will also need a reference to nunit and a reference to the NUnit.Framework assemmbly. If you are using visual studio 2008 professional you can just create a new test project and add a unit test.